# How to send image and PDF in attachment using Microsoft graph SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph SDK for sending mail using office 365 account from my iOS application recently I am able to send mail body but I am not able to send attachments with it, I am referring [This](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fileattachment) link for the attachment but could not able to send attachments.

I have tried to hit https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail URL using following JSON

{
"message":{
            "subject":"Meet for lunch?",
            "hasAttachments":true,
      "body":{
            "contentType":"Text",
            "content":"The new cafeteria is open."
             },
      "toRecipients":[
                     {
                       "emailAddress":{
                                  "address":"abc@123.onmicrosoft.com"
                                      }
                     }
                     ],
      "attachments":[
                    {
                 "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",
                 "name":"menu.png",
                 "Content-Type":"multipart/mixed"
                 "contentBytes":"base64 string"
                    }
                    ]
        },
"saveToSentItems":"false"
}

with header of

"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

"Authorization" : "bearer"

but I am getting status code 415 with unsupported media type.

Answer (score 1):

Ratzz,

The Content-Type property is for the attachment itself, not for the top level of the MIME message. So the value should be "image/png" rather than "multipart.mixed". Similarly, you would use "application/pdf" for an attached PDF doc or image.

Please give it a try.

regards,
Dana Birkby

Answer (score -1):

this is an old question, but i just hit this issue and if you remove  `"Content-Type":"multipart/mixed"` you should be fine or add a comma after it ;)